# Which jquery event triggers when i click on bootstrap datepicker calender and without selecting date click outside?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Which jquery event triggers when we click on bootstrap datepicker calender and without selecting date click outside?

Comment: Could you include a fiddle with some code that you've tried already? Would make it easier for others to help. Could have ruled out the obvious suggestion of .on("click",...); already.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [`bootstrap-datepicker`](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#show) docs:-

**show**

- This event fires immediately when the date picker is displayed.

**hide**

- This event is fired immediately when the date picker is hidden (or in your words, without selecting date click outside).

Comment: so how would i write something on that hide event, Actually when i am clicking out without selecting date then my datepicker textbox values changes to month one less then its selected in calender, so i want to increase month by one everytime i click outside without selecting date.

Comment: @VivekKumar: Its already mentioned in the docs. Use it like: `$('.datepicker').datepicker()
    .on('hide', function(e){
        // your logic here...
    });`